# Whitespace before EOF

Tags: c

I am a beginner at C. Trying my hand at file handling. When I run the file, there's a space just before EOF. What is that? Since I have 3 cases one for blank space, 1 for EOF and default for normal characters I could not understand what that specific space is. Please help me understand this. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void write_f(FILE *f_ptr)
{
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a line\n");
    //(assigning to var = taking input) compare to new line
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') //stop once encounters a new line or enter
    {
        //putting to file
        putc(ch, f_ptr);
    }
    putc("\n", f_ptr); //putting a new line in file
}

void total_char(FILE *f_ptr)
{
    fseek(f_ptr, 0, SEEK_END); //moving ptr to end of file
    //ftell calculates the distance from current and returns the int
    printf("Total characters: %d\n", ftell(f_ptr));

    //fseek(f_ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    rewind(f_ptr); //both moves ptr to start of file
}

void show_pos(FILE *f_ptr)
{
    long int offset = 0L;
    char ch;

    //returns non-zero value if ptr reached the end of file else returns 0
    while(feof(f_ptr) == 0) //loops till feof returns a non-zero value
    {
        fseek(f_ptr, offset++, 0); //offset increments after execution
        ch = getc(f_ptr);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case ' ':
                printf("Character SPACE was encountered at %1d\n", ftell(f_ptr));
                break;
            case EOF:
                printf("END OF FILE was encountered at %1d\n", ftell(f_ptr));
                break;
            default:
                printf("Character %c was encountered at %1d\n", ch, ftell(f_ptr));
                break;
        }
    }

    //what the hell is the space before EOF?
}

int main()
{
    FILE *f_ptr;

    //overwrites if exists else creates
    f_ptr = fopen("H:\\Coding\\C\\Book\\userinrandomaccess_test.txt", "w+");

    write_f(f_ptr);
    total_char(f_ptr);
    show_pos(f_ptr);

    fclose(f_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that "there's a space just before EOF"?

Comment: Did you think of `'\r'`, tabulator, shift+space, `'\n'`?

Comment: You are doing `putc("\n",f_ptr);` That is wrong. It is flagged by the compiler so your code doesn't even compile. That should be: `putc('\n',f_ptr);`

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Also `char ch;` should be `int ch;`. None of the i/o functions take or return a `char` type for a single character. A "character" is not `char` they just begin with the same four letters.

Comment: `char ch;` **no no no** ==> **must be** `int ch;`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing:

```
putc("\n",f_ptr);
```

`putc` expects an `int` as its first arg. But, you're passing it a `char` pointer. So, the compiler will flag this.

It should be:

```
putc('\n',f_ptr);
```

It you ignore the compiler warnings/errors and run the program, the `putc` will output a [seemingly] random character instead of newline. That's because it depends upon the low byte of the final *address* of the `"\n"` string.

On your system, you got a space. On my system, it output `)`.

This is an example of UB (undefined behavior). This is the case that merely produces wrong results instead of crashing with a segmentation fault.